# Unity 3D - Possible for it to render a simple colored spot?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, 3d, unity-game-engine

I am sure this will be easy for a Unity expert.

If we were making a game like FLOW [Click here to see FLOW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow&hl=en)

and all we needed were some simple colored circles which the user must click and drag, then can these be rendered by Unity, or do we need to actually import a PNG of a circle?

I am sure Unity would be capable of rendering a flat solid circle, which I think would look better and behave better when scaling up/down? And would it be lighter/more efficient on the game engine?

A solid colored sphere perhaps, or a cylinder with minimal depth? Whats the best solution?

Thanks a lot
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Best is not defined. You could draw a circle with a triangle fan. Or you could use a plane with a shader (or the previous triangle fan). The benefit of both these techniques is that they are possible to anti-alias (AA). The advantage of the shader is that it is indeed a circle at infinite precision and the AA can be made very good quality.

The real question is why do you want a 3d engine in the first place? Heres a example of a shader, rest of the scene except the shader makes no sense.

http://webglplayground.net/saved/ng3BkJNHfN

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply

Its Unity because thats what our guy knows how to use. He has asked us to supply the circles as PNGs, but they aren't super sharp once they are in the game, and I figured that a program like Unity must be able to render a simple circle effectively.

For me, "best" means no blurred edges, scalable, and light on the engine/CPU etc.

Comment: Well consider using a 2d toolkit. Added a example shader in webglplayground. (principle is the same)

Comment: For the rest, I agree with the answer. Drawing circles would be a better idea. Though you have to figure out how to connect those circles! Drawing the circles may be better looking, since you won't have many circles (thus not eating up calculation time from the processor) and AA can be applied. Connecting those circles like has been done in FLOW is a whole other story.